# AlertDialog Closing on Overlay Click

Tags: android

Trying to debug a bit of code. I have a AlertDialog with a positive and negative listener set. On an Android 2.3.3 device everything works as expected. A user has to choose between two options in order to continue. However, on my 4.1.1 device a user can click anywhere on the screen to dismiss the dialog. Not sure what is getting called that is dismissing the dialog box. I've looked at [Android AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) and [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) but I can't find any helpful information. Any help on why this is occurring would be appreciated. The code for the dialog is below

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.titleString));

builder.setPositiveButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.option1),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Things Happen Here
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

builder.setNegativeButton(this.getResources().getString(R.string.option2),
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Things Happen Here
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

AlertDialog demoAlert = builder.create();
demoAlert.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `cancelable` to false:

```
builder.setCancelable(false);
```